# How does this Java method receive it's data?

Tags: java

I'm new to Java and programming in general, and I was wondering why this program works, especially the String s part. How does that method get the data for it to continue?

```
public class NewMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        printer("hey");
    }

    static void printer(String s)
    {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll be the bad guy and say that you should read a tutorial.

Comment: Also, figuring out why a program works is how you learn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`String s` is a parameter on a method.  You can call a method and pass it a parameter.  The method will then be able to use the variable.

In this example, you are passing "hey" as the parameter to `printer`.  Printer then uses the `s` variable to print it out to the console (that's what `System.out.println` does.  It prints things to the console).

You can call `printer` multiple times with different parameters if you want.  Try changing the code to this:

```
public class NewMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        printer("hey");
        printer("how");
        printer("are");
        printer("you?");
    }

    static void printer(String s)
    {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

You'll see that this prints all those words in order.  That's because the parameters is different in each of these `printer` calls.

Answer (score 3):

That's just how the language works.

When you invoke a method

```
printer("hey");
```

A copy of the value of the argument, the `"hey"` part, is bound to the parameter the method declares, the `String s` part in

```
static void printer(String s)
```

[The official tutorial is here (for objects, but the same applies for `static` methods).](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/usingobject.html)